# HttpErrorResponse in Angular Application | PHP Api

Tags: php, angular, http

Im using angular httpclient and php in back-end for handling data in my angular application. But im getting following error when im trying to save data.

Error Im Getting

[image]

Im using following **database.service.ts** angular service to connect whit database and pass data

```
insertFabricData(value){
    return this._http.post("http://localhost/jeleena-api/fabric.php",value).pipe(map(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }));
  }
```

And Im Using **fabric.component.ts**to call database.service.ts file from front end

```
saveFormData(){
    this._databaseService.insertFabricData(this.fabric).subscribe(msg => {
       console.log('yes');
       console.log(msg);
    });
  }
```

Following is my php code which is running on my localhost **fabric.php**

```
<?php
//Get Data From Front End
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
//Create Database Connection
include "db-connection.php";
//SQL Statements
$sql = "INSERT INTO fabric_details (bill_id,fabric_swetch,fabric_width,unit,fabric_category,colour,
total,temp_meter,temp_price,actual_meter,actual_price,finish) VALUES
 ('$data->bill_number','$data->fabric_swetch','$data->fabric_width','$data->unit',
 '$data->fabric_category','$data->colour','$data->total','$data->temp_meter','$data->temp_price','$data->actual_meter',
 '$data->actual_price','$data->finish')";
//Check Null Values
if($data){
    //Run The Query Only Name Exitsqty
    $qry = $conn->query($sql);
}
//Close Database Connection
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Would suggest inspect the API response in chrome developer tool and validate the JSON response format is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because, the http post try to parse result from api ,

but you not return anything from **fabric.php** , i dont know what exactly return result in php , if we doesn't have return value.

but so far i know, when http post try to parse, he get the invalid format, that's why you get error.

Comment: how to return a message from fabric.php

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script, maybe help you.